# Xamarin's Device.StartTimer Overlapping

Tags: c#, xamarin

Under TestBtn_Clicked,  I have two Device.StartTimer; one for Addition, the other is for Subtraction. I want them to be executed sequentially; after the first is finished, the second starts. But, they are executing like in parallel. This is the first part of the problem.
The second is that in the very beginning, after TestBtn is clicked, nothing happens until the specified time span passes. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
 private void TestBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration), () =>
            {
                if (numberOfQuestions > 0)
                {
                    HelpingMethods.Addition(numOfDecimal, min, max, Num1Lbl, Num2Lbl, SignLbl, Ch1Btn, Ch2Btn, Ch3Btn, Ch4Btn, Ch5Btn, Ch6Btn);
                    numberOfQuestions--;
                   
                    HelpingMethods.CounterInSeconds(duration, TimerLbl);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        
        
        //For subtraction method and should start after previous (Addition) is finished
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durationS), () =>
            {
                if (numberOfQuestionsS > 0)
                {  
                    HelpingMethods.Subtraction(numOfDecimalS, minS, maxS, Num1Lbl, Num2Lbl, SignLbl, Ch1Btn, Ch2Btn, Ch3Btn, Ch4Btn, Ch5Btn, Ch6Btn);
                    numberOfQuestionsS--;

                    HelpingMethods.CounterInSeconds(durationS, TimerLbl);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });           
    } 
 

public static void CounterInSeconds(int timeLeft, Label TimerLbl)
    {
        int duration = timeLeft;
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                timeLeft -= 1;

                if (timeLeft >= 0)
                {
                    TimerLbl.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
                    if (timeLeft == 0)
                    {
                        TimerLbl.Text = duration.ToString();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }
```

Comment: to start with, use System.Timers.Timer instead.  In your current impelementation, if you want B to start after A finishes, then you need to call B from A's completion handler.

Comment: Thank you Jason for the quick response. As for calling B from A completion handler, it works but makes it more difficult to randomize the questions. I wish there is a way to execute them sequentially. Then, I can, using random number, condition their execution, and thus generate random questions. Also, even with your suggested approach, the lag in the beginning is still there. As for the System.Timers.Timer, currently I am trapped in Device.StartTimer and couldn't falsify the return value. I need someone to falsify it, so that I can move to System.Timers.Timer

Comment: the "lag" is because the only code you have in TestBtn_Clicked is to start your timer.  None of the code inside of the timer handler fires until the first time the timer fires.  If you want to fire it once before the first timer, you need to add that code inside TestBtn_Clicked

Comment: Always thank you, Jason, for your help. Perfect! But, isn't there a way to have two Device.StartTimer execute separately, first first?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple timers running.

Comment: I made methods async with task return, and used await and Task.Delay as timer. I see this is cleaner, easier and more concise than using Device.Timer. Thank you Jason.

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer and mark it later so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: OK. I will share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem has been stated in the question. To capture the essence of the problem without going into unrelated details, the code has been rewritten in a simple way. The solution, which is credited to Jason in the comments, has been commented on. You can delete the statements commented on to see the problem.
In summary, the first problem is that the two timers execute together rather than sequentially. The second is that the execution of the method inside the timer is delayed by the amount of timeSpan specified in the timer, before the method is fired. The first was solved by calling the second method inside Device.Timer() of the first, just before the Boolean value is evaluated to false. The second was solved by calling the method once before entering Device.Timer(). Here is the code.

```
using System; using System.ComponentModel; using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test1
{
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int aDuration = 4;
    int bDuration = 7;
    int aCount = 3;
    int bCount = 5;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   private void TestBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AInsideTimer();
    }


    public void A()
    {          
        TestLbl.Text = "AMethod: " + aCount;
        aCount--;
    }

    public void B()
    {         
        TestLbl.Text = "BMethode: " + bCount;
        bCount--;
    }

    
    
    void AInsideTimer()
    {
        CounterInSeconds(aDuration, TimerLbl); //Start the timer
        A(); //Start the method before entering the timer; because method inside Device.Timer() will not fire except after the time span passes.
       

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(aDuration), () =>
        {
            if (aCount > 0)
            {
                A();
                CounterInSeconds(aDuration, TimerLbl);
                return true;
            }
            BInsideTimer(); //Here you put the second method to execute. 
            return false;
        });
    }
    
    void BInsideTimer()
    {
        CounterInSeconds(bDuration, TimerLbl); //Start the timer
        B(); //Start the method before entering the timer; because method inside Device.Timer() will not fire except after the time span passes.

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bDuration), () =>
        {
            if (bCount > 0)
            {
                B();
                CounterInSeconds(bDuration, TimerLbl);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

     void CounterInSeconds(int timeLeft, Label TimerLbl)
    {
        
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),  () =>
        {
            timeLeft -= 1;

            if (timeLeft >= 0)
            {
                TimerLbl.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
                return true;
            }
            //Here you put the next method, if any, to execute. 
            return false;
        });
     }
   }
}
```

However, I ended up using Task.Delay(TimeSpan), which is more concise and straightforward. The code below does the same job as the previous; less code but more intelligible, at least to me.

```
using System;using System.ComponentModel;using System.Threading.Tasks;using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test2
{

[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int aDuration = 4;
    int bDuration = 7;
    int aCount = 3;
    int bCount = 5;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async private void TestBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await A();
        await B();
    }

    async Task A()
    {
        while (aCount > 0)
        {
            TestLbl.Text = "MethodeA: " + aCount;
            aCount--;
            await CounterInSeconds(aDuration, TimerLbl);
        }
    }

    async Task B()
    {
        while (bCount > 0)
        {
            TestLbl.Text = "MethodB: " + bCount;
            bCount--;
            await CounterInSeconds(bDuration, TimerLbl);
        }
       

    }
    
    public static async Task CounterInSeconds(int timeLeft, Label TimerLbl)
    {
        while (timeLeft >= 0)
        {
            TimerLbl.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
            timeLeft -= 1;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
      }
   }
}
```